# php mail function - how can changing From: in header cause email not to be sent?

Tags: php, sendmail

The one email From:support@lead.com works fine.  But when changed to john.doe@lead.com it doesn't work? See below.

Both are valid email addresses (fictitious for this example) in the domain from which they are sent.

I have the question into Netfirms support too.  I expect to move to phpmailer or API to a ESP (e.g., mailchimp) account soon, but this is just bugging me that the little change breaks the email function.

Code:

Works:

```
$headers = "Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: support@lead.com' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Bcc: bcc@lead.com' . "\r\n";   
//   $headers .= 'Return-Path: bcc@lead.com' . "\r\n";  
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
if (!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f bcc@mylead.com")) echo ("Message delivery failed");
```

Doesn't Work: (only changed support to john.doe):

```
$headers = "Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: john.doe@lead.com' . "\r\n"; 
//   $headers .= 'Return-Path: bcc@lead.com' . "\r\n";  
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
if (!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f bcc@lead.com")) echo ("Message delivery failed");
```

Comment: 1) try another account, without dots in it 2) try existing account

Comment: Huh.  We think a like.  I tried johndoe@lead.com.  It didn't work either.  However that is not a valid email address on the domain.

Comment: And is `support@lead.com` a valid one?

Comment: What does the mail server log says?

Comment: yes - support@lead.com is valid as is john.doe@lead.com.  I tried johndoe@lead.com and it didn't work either.  However, johndoe is not a valid email address at the domain.

Comment: I didn't know about a mail server log.  I can't find any documentation about one at netfirms.  I have a support question into them.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Do the email addresses need to be configured in the server in order to include them in the From:?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how this really should matter, but you're mixing \n and \r\n in the headers, which may confuse your mail server... Would you mind to try this out?

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I'll try that again.  I did try it and it didn't make a difference.   At the time I was passing the From in a function call, so I stripped it all out and just used the hard coded one that I posted.  I'll try adding the \r and see if it works in the hard coded one.